# How to use `where` condition in options collections select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use `where` condition in options select? The following code is not working:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@group,:groupname, :groupname).where(User_id: @user.id)%>
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What is "options select tag"?

Comment: "How can I use where condition in options select" - you don't. This is not an activerecord relation/query. But `@group` likely is. So if it would anywhere, it'd be on `@group`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  thanks.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Another method? Why not use this one?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  with out where condition it is working.

Comment: But I want to fetch group which I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options_from_collection_for_select` takes a collection of records and options and returns a HTML string. So that of course won’t work as you are calling `.where` on a string.

You need to call it on the collection instead.

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@group.where(User_id: @user.id), :groupname, :groupname) %>
```